# Are we doing mild consequences and stress right?

Tags: dresden-files, fate, stress

After reading through the book and reading up on consequences, i can't help but feel that we might be treating stress and mild consequences the wrong way.  Say we've just been in a fight, after the fight ends that's considered, for the most part, the end of a scene right?  And if i recall correctly stress and mild consequences heal after a scene.  So, are we doing this right or am i missing/misreading something?

Comment: Scenes don't necessarily end at the end of the fight. If you're in the same location and the GM hasn't narrated time passing, any play following the fight is in the same scene.

Comment: YEah, i'm trying to break that habbit that just because a fight is over doesn't mean the scene is over.  you never know someone might have been watching and could attack you at any moment.

Comment: DFRPG treats Scenes very much like you would a TV show or a play, and as such they're extremely loose. Often times you would end a fight, but still be in the same scene as @Seven suggests.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You're not.

1. Seven is right - the end of a fight isn't the end of a scene. It **can be**, but it isn't necessarily - especially if you lose. Fleeing a failed assault does not grant Stress recovery!
2. Mild consequences last until the end of the scene AFTER they get to start
   recovery. Just stopping a fight doesn't start recovery.

**EDIT:** Mild consequences are cleared at the **end of the scene after the one in which recovery begins**. I never let PCs begin recovery in the same scene in which a consequence was invoked - those are two very separate emotional beats and I can't see how they'd be in the same scene. Here's a more detailed breakdown:

At some point, you have a fight and take a consequence, that's one scene.

When you go home and have a breather, talking with your compatriots about the consequences of that fight and where to go next, that's another scene. If in this scene injured players get tended to and shocked / rattled players get to relax or rest, then you can count this as the scene in which **recovery begins**.

Next, they players go to the bad guy's stronghold - they have to press the advantage their victory brought while they can. **They still have all of their consequences.**

When the scene above **ends**, the mild consequences which began recovery as stated, **are now cleared**. Any new consequences incurred since then cannot even begin recovery!

Comment: +1. Try to think of a scene as one chapter in a book.  I know that some authors tend to split their chapters on cliff hangers so the analogy breaks down a little but it should give you a good idea for how long a scene is.

Comment: Nice breakdown of what the rule looks like in practice.

Comment: @Seven - thanks. I realized I hadn't been clear enough in the original answer.

Answer (score 4):

Mild consequences and stress tracks are cleared when the characters get a chance to catch their breath. For health stress, this means taking a few minutes off physical activity. For mental stress, closing your eyes, meditating for a few minutes or listening to a song should suffice. Social stress could clear when the debate is over or when you remove yourself from the scene.

They do not clear as long as the pressure is on. If you run away from a fight, the health stress remains even if the scene changes from combat to pursuit.